# Is there a FF equivalent to chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm porting a Chrome extension to Firefox WebExtensions and I'm stuck on finding a workaround for `chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged`.

My FF Webextension contains a Page Action that must be shown when navigating on certain websites. However, none of the listeners in the available API seem to allow this.

In particular I've tried:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onChange);
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(onChange);
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(onChange);
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onChange);
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded(onChange);
chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget(onChange);
```

Are there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to show the pageAction manually because declarativeContent API is [not yet supported](https://bugzil.la/1435864).

```
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
```

In case the rules are based on URL matching the implementation is quite easy:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.match(/something/)) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
});
```

However in case it's DOM element-based you'll have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.match(/something/)) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: 'document.querySelector(' + JSON.stringify(someSelector) + ')'
        }, function(results) {
            if (results[0]) {
                chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
            } else {
                chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
            }
        });
    } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
});
```

This is a very simplified code. It can be enhanced to look for elements while a page is loading.

Comment: In case of a content-script based approach `onUpdated` listener may not be even needed.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` works once I'm navigating to different sites, but not when I first open a tab. Will post my workaround below!

Comment: FYI: Your code will inject and execute the content script multiple times on most pages. The `tabs.onUpdated` event is often fired multiple times per page load with `tab.status === 'complete'` (a bug IMO). Possible: look for `changeInfo.url && changeInfo.status==='complete'`. For a more detailed look at the events available see [tabs.onUpdated.addListener's changeInfo.status goes from undefined to Complete without ever going to loading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39033812/3773011). Code in that answer can help investigate the events available and determine what criteria works for the situation.

Comment: Correct. But sometimes there's nothing wrong with multiple execution in case the page action should be hidden once the element disappears from the page. Although in that case a MutationObserver or setInterval callback seems a better choice. Actually, I've meant to use `changeInfo.status` initially, so thanks, the answer is updated.

Comment: For the simple case (execute & terminate) of the code here, multiple execution is OK. People run into problems when they multiply inject something that does not fully terminate. Yeah, for CSS selectors in `chrome.declarativeContent` there is not, really, an *effective* solution other than injecting a stay-resident content script into every page matching the URL (easier? with *manifest.json* `"content_scripts"`) that uses a MutationObserver or `setTimeout` then sends a message to the background script upon match. `chrome.declarativeContent` is, after all, specifically a shortcut for doing that.

Comment: I would recommend not checking for `changeInfo.url`. I just saw that at least in Chrome, this is not set during the `'complete'` event. Instead, it would probably make sense to check for `tab.url`.

Comment: based on this answer I created a port for an addon, thank you! You can see the changes here: https://github.com/VLCTechHub/publisher-browser-extension/commit/8f86cf95623ff5504d3dc9e478dd8eafa0cceb5e

Answer (score 0):

For simple URL matching, and for new tabs as well as changes to an existing tab, this works:

- include the `tabs` permission in the manifest.

.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.match(/something/)) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  } else if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
  }
});
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.match(/something/)) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
  } else if (tab.url) {
    chrome.pageAction.hide(tab.id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The best equivalent so far seems to be:

```
var target = "<all_urls>";
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(onChange, {urls: [target]});
```

(`onChange()` includes matching the current URL with a regex and then `chrome.pageAction.show(tabInfo.id);`)

Comment: It'll fire on all types of web requests, including images and scripts and styles. Use filtering to limit it to the main frame only: `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(onChange, {urls: [target], types: ['main_frame']});`